# What part of integration am I missing?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate $$\int_1^2 \sqrt{\frac {1}{4t^2}+3+9t^2}$$

I first got rid of the denominator $4$ and got $$\int_1^2 \sqrt{\frac {1}{t^2}+12+36t^2}.$$

Then I integrated and got $\frac {2}{3} (\frac {-1}{t^1}+12t+12t^3)(36).$

However, it doesn't seem right. Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: $(6t+\frac{1}{t})^2 = 36t^2+12+\frac{1}{t^2}$

Comment: Also, $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^2}+3+9t^2} = \color{Red}{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+12+36t^2}$$

Comment: Why is there $\frac {1}{2}$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $t >0$,
$$
\left(3t+\frac{1}{2t}\right)^2=9t^2+3+\frac{1}{4t^2}
$$ then one may use it for the *initial* integral.

Comment: If I put a square root over $(3t+\frac {1}{2t})^2$, wouldn't I just wind up with $(3t+\frac {1}{2t})$?

Comment: @nyorkr23 Yes, then you get $\int_1^2 (3t+\frac1{2t})\:dt$ which is easier to evaluate.

Comment: From there, the integrated "answer" would be $\frac {3+ln|2t|}{2}$?

Comment: It would rather be $3 \cdot \frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln |t|$, because $(\frac{t^2}{2})'=t$ and $(\frac{1}{2}\ln |t|)'=\frac{1}{2t}$.